# Try/Catch with an SQL connection

Tags: c#, using-statement, try-catch-finally

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Correct use of Try Catch for the SQL connection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419746/correct-use-of-try-catch-for-the-sql-connection-in-c-sharp)

when you write a code like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryGetPcPrintDetails, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    }
                } // reader closed and disposed up here

            } // command disposed here
        }
```

Is there a need to catch an exception in order to close the connection? For example, if there's some problem in the second using or in the do stuff section.. do I need to somehow do try/finally and close the connection?

Comment: If it's in a using, it'll get disposed: ["Clean up resources allocated with either using statements, or finally blocks. Prefer using statements to automatically clean up resources when exceptions are thrown. Use finally blocks to clean up resources that don't implement IDisposable."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-trycatchfinally-blocks-to-recover-from-errors-or-release-resources).

Comment: a `using` is just a shorthand for `try{..}finally{obj.Dispose()}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception so many questions that address this here on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create connection inside `using{}` block, connection get automatically close at the end of `using` block/scope.Automatically in the sense, `Dispose()` method get called whenever you leave the scope of `Using{}`

[SQL connection class : MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: even in case there's an exception before you reach the end of the using scope?

Comment: @YonatanNir Dispose() gets called *when you leave* the scope at any point, by whatever means. A return statement on the first line of the scope would cause Dispose() to get called. "At the end" isn't quite how I'd express the concept.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, already answered your question.. I want to know why people downvoted

Comment: I am seeing 0 for votes, what's the issue? Just my two cents, it's been addressed many times before, we don't need another... I could have answered and so could of others, but they may have felt that a comment would better suffice, similar/exact questions already on SO etc...

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Not my question. I did not downvote. I suspect they may have downvoted because it's a very terse answer with no references, and/or because "at the end" is a very easily misunderstood way to describe what's happening. You'll rarely know why people downvote around here; perhaps they assume it should be as obvious to you as it is to them (though if it were, you'd hardly have written what you did).

Comment: @EdPlunkett, totally agree with your point... I updated my answer with msdn link

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Very often, when you give a reason, they argue and it's a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: People downvoted because they don't like when people are answering questions they think that should be closed. So you got downvoted for helping